# While calculating the power spectral density (PSD), why is there a roll-off at the end depending on the sampling rate?

Tags: fft, power-spectral-density

[image]
[image]

In these power spectral density plots shown above (taken from the web [1](https://www.menlosystems.com/assets/documents/Timing-Distribution-System-Brochure-complete.pdf),[[2]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.01401.pdf)), the spectra show a roll-off at the highest frequencies, as shown in the figure. For my own example, when I calculate PSD from time domain data taken with a sampling rate of 10 MSa/s using Welche's method, this roll-off appears at half the sampling rate in the spectra, which is after 5 MHz. Is this an artifact of the FFT or Welche's method, or could you please explain the reason behind this roll-off?

I have attached two figures where I see this roll-off.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's just an indication that the dataset has a lowpass characteristic; that is, as frequency increases, the spectral content decays toward zero. This is a common attribute of signals, especially signals that have had [anti-aliasing filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing_filter) applied before digitization. It doesn't have anything to do with Welch's method; for example, try generating white Gaussian noise and see that the PSD estimate is nearly flat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It many  cases this is caused by the data acquisition system. Most A/D converters have an anti-aliasing low pass filter. The choice of filter depends on the specific application but typically the cutoff frequency is at 80%-90% of the Nyquist frequency.

Comment: That is interesting!

Comment: Thank you so much for the informed answer @Hilmar.  Let me understand it more clearly. I understand that the DAQ may have anti-aliasing filters ranging close to the Nyquist frequency.  Are these used in addition to the downsampling filters, (FIR filter)?

Comment: It's the Analog to Digital converter that needs and anti-aliasing filter. Whether you need one for a D/A converter depends on the application.  Down sampling also requires and anti-aliasing filter

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it. @Hilmar