# Why do we have a negative gain after a certain point in frequency domain for a channel filter?

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications, frequency-response, butterworth

Why do we have a negative gain(i.e. not negative as in polarity but gain < 1) after a certain point (1500 Hz). What is the reason and purpose for this. Why is that point the same for both DC and AC coupling of the baseband channel filter - Butterworth?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [While calculating the power spectral density (PSD), why is there a roll-off at the end depending on the sampling rate?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/84991/while-calculating-the-power-spectral-density-psd-why-is-there-a-roll-off-at-t)

Comment: @Irreducible here the sampling rate changes but the roll of remains constant. So yeah thought that was the answer but nah

Answer (score 1):

This is not a negative gain. The ordinate axis is in a logarithmic scale, namely in dB. Negative values mean gains smaller than 1. The roll-off behind the corner frequency is the whole point of this filter.
As for AC vs DC coupling: this only affects very low frequencies near the DC point if done in a regular fashion. A typical application example for this would be audio circuits. In some cases you need AC coupling, which actually means DC *de*coupling, without affecting the audible audioband, so you design your input stage with a highpass behavior with corner frequency between 0 and 20Hz.

Comment: I do know it is not negative as in polarity. I framed my q differently  now. I wanna know why it rolls off after 1500 Hz. Is due to power loss at high frequency. What is the reason is what I am after.

Comment: This is the way the filter was designed. It lets low frequencies pass and attenuates high frequencies. I'm not sure what else you want to know. Electrically speaking and looking at a simple first order RC lowpass, the high frequency components are burned in the R, because the C looks to them like a short.

Answer (score 0):

negative signal [dBV] [dBmV] [dBuV] or power [dBW] [dBmW] means **Loss**.

[dB] below 0, below here meaning negative, is Gain < 1.